# Why are the cluster different between dendogram and cluster analysis?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca, hierarchical-clustering

I have 34 plots with 7 different variables. I want to cluster the data and find subgroups.
I computed a Principal component analysis (PCA) and a hierarchical clustering on the principal components. I made a dendogram and a cluster analyse. The results from the dendogram and the cluster analysis are different, e. g. cluster 3 from the dendogram contains 4 plots and from the cluster analysis contains 6 plots.

[image]

I expected the cluster to be the same.

```
library(vegan)
library(writexl)
library(corrplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("cmartin/ggConvexHull")
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)
library(ggConvexHull)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(viridis)
```

```
Cluster <- read.csv('Data.csv', sep = ';')
```

```
res.pca <- PCA(Cluster, scale.unit = TRUE, ncp = 4, graph = FALSE) # Compute PCA with ncp = 4
```

```
res.hcpc <- HCPC(res.pca, graph = F) # Compute hierarchical clustering on principal components
```

```
# fviz_dend: Enhanced Visualization of Dendrogram
factoextra::fviz_dend(res.hcpc, 
                      cex = 0.7,   # Label size
                      palette = c("gold1", "chartreuse4","sienna3"), 
                      show_labels = T,
                      rect = TRUE, rect_fill = TRUE, # Add rectangle around groups
                      rect_border = c("gold1", "chartreuse4","sienna3"),     # Rectangle color
                      labels_track_height = 0.8,     # Augment the room for labels
                      )
```

```
# fviz_cluster: Enhanced Visualization of Cluster analysis
fviz_cluster(res.hcpc,
             #repel = TRUE,            # Avoid label overlapping
             show.clust.cent = TRUE,   # Show cluster centers
             geom = c("point", "text"),
             #palette = "jco",
             palette = c("gold1","sienna3", "chartreuse4"), 
             ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
            )
```

Comment: Hello Steffi. You determine the number of groups you want to display after hierarchical clustering. `fviz_dend` has a k parameter to determine this or h parameter to set te cut level.